# pidstat and perl!

Tags: scripts, perl

I hope I phrase this question correctly.

I want to write pidstat into a perl script so that when a user runs it he/she is asked for a PID the script then runs pidstat with that specific PID and returns the result? 
I know how to request the user for a pid and then set the script to read the STDIN, but i'm stuck on how to call on pidstat in perl!! Driving me nuts!
Please help and be gentle I'm only little!

Comment: The almighty google says there's a CPAN module for that: [Proc::ProcessTable](http://search.cpan.org/~jwb/Proc-ProcessTable-0.53/ProcessTable.pm). It appears to be packaged as `libproc-processtable-perl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `perldoc -f open`, and do something like:

```
 open(P, "/bin/date --date=\"$since\" '+%Y,%m,%e' |" ) || die "can't fork: $!";
           while (<P>) {
             chomp;
             $tmp = $_;
             $tmp =~ s/,0/,/;   # remove %m leading zero for months less than 10.
             @base = split /,/, $tmp, 4;
             if ( $#base != 2 ) { # only expect 3 fieds from /bin/date
               die "Cannot parse \"$since\" with /bin/date\n";
             }
           }
  close P    || die "bad /bin/date";
```

}